# Jest - mock variables inside class

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a class with config variables

```
import  config  from '@/libs/config';

export class Logger {

  constructor () {
    this.level = this.testMethod(config.LOGGER);
    this.target_name = this.testMethod(config.LOGGER_TARGETS);
   }
```

And for example I have a method, where I use *config* variables

```
  testMethod(config) {
    return config;
  }
```

Is it possible to mock up the `config variables` (like config.LOGGER or config.LOGGER_TARGETS)  to test my `testMethod`?
How could I access and set it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can test `testMethod` right now. 
The approach varies based on what you want to test.
If you want to test that this method is called during creating a new instance, just mock it and check if it was called with required arguments. If you want to test that `loggerInstance.level` and `loggerInstance.target_name` has correct values, just check them afterward.

If you want to test method's logic – call it with params and check returned value.

Also, you can implement dependency inversion and get Logger class to receive config variables via constructor params. Pass params from `@/libs/config` in code that use this class and pass test params in tests. It's much better from the perspective of scalability and architecture.